# Show that no two of the three sets ⌀, {⌀}, and {{⌀}} are equal to each other.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm doing this course on logic and we have an exam from set theory coming up,  "Show that no two of the three sets ⌀, {⌀}, and {{⌀}} are equal to each other." is one of the problems in the workbook we were assigned and I can't for the life of me even begin to solve this. I have the general knowledge surrounding empty sets and operations, but I don't know how I would go about writing a solution to this problem.

Comment: The empty set ($\emptyset$) has **no** elements (see definition).

Comment: $\{ \emptyset \}$ has **one** element (the empty set). See [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_enumeration).

Comment: Two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal if $A$ is a subset of $B$ and vice versa. $A$ is a subset of $B$ if for all $a\in A$ it is also true that $a\in B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Two sets are equal if both can be written as a subset of the other. I.e. $A = B \iff A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

In your case, The sets $\{ \emptyset \}$ and $ \{ \{ \emptyset \} \} $ contain elements which $\emptyset$ does not. Further, the set $ \{ \{ \emptyset \} \} $ contains an element which $\{ \emptyset \}$ does not.

Once you realise what I'm talking about, the answer should be clear. If it's not, I suggest that you re-read your definitions and notation for sets and elements of sets.